# getting value from a chained promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, google-cloud-firestore

im really new to this of promises and im getting headaches trying to understand this, so now im trying to get an answer from a method that returns a promise, then i catch the value in a conditional and make some other operations

```
let addService = async(req, res) => {
    checkCategoryExists(param).then(result => {
        if(result){
           // code here
        }
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}


let checkCategoryExists = async(param) => {
    let docs = db.collection(collectionName).doc(param);
    docs.get()
        .then(categoryDoc => {
            if(categoryDoc.exists){
                if(categoryDoc.data().param== param){
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        })
        .catch(err => false);
}
```

the method "checkCategoryExists" is a query to a firestore db. When i tried to check if result variable is true or false, it happens to be undefined. its not with ".then()" that i get to catch the value from the returned promise? if someone can help me, thanks in advance

Comment: i'm pretty sure if you are getting undefined it is because you aren't returning the result of your query should be `return docs.get().then.....`

Comment: @DLowther's diagnosis is right.  The simple fix is `docs.get()...`

Answer (score 0):

So as mentioned above I think your issue is based on not returning the results of your document search so both examples below handle that.

I also noticed that you were using async tags on your functions but not ever using await so I wanted to give examples of both ways of doing it in case you wanted to use Async/Await but weren't certain how.

In the promise chain example I'm relying on the syntax of arrow functions to create the returns (no `{}` means return right side of equation) since none of your given code requires data manipulation before return (if your actual code needs that you should of course use brackets and remember your return statement :D )

If you choose to use Async/Await you can structure the code much more closely to synchronous examples and use try catch statements. Sometimes I find this syntax more clear if I have to do a lot of processing/manipulation before returning a result.

Good Luck :)!

```js
// Promise Chains
const addService = (req, res) => 
  checkCategoryExists(param)
    .then(result => /* do stuff */)
    .catch(err => console.error(err.message));
  
const checkCategoryExists = param => 
  db.collection(collectionName.doc(param)
    .get()
    .then(categoryDoc => 
      Promise.resolve((categoryDoc.exists && categoryDoc.data().param === param))
    );
    
// OR using Async/Await
const addService async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const catExists = await checkCategoryExists(param);
    if (!catExists) {
      throw new Error('error code');
    }
    
    // Do Stuff.
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

const checkCategoryExists = async param => {
  try {
    const docs = await db.collection(collectionName)
      .doc(param)
      .get();
    
    return (docs.exists && docs.data().param === param);
  } catch (error) { 
    console.error(error) 
  }
}
```